# What is the output voltage of this simple circuit?

Tags: voltage

Background: I'm trying to learn circuits from http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws but no practice problems are provided so the problems I [find](http://www.tutorvista.com/physics/diode-circuit-problems?view=simple) to work are out of order from what I've learned so far. How would you find the output voltage and current below:
The silicon diode has a .7v  diode drop:

[image]

Specifically, I don't understand what to do about the grounded branch and the non circular path followed by $v_0$.
(Answer :- 2.07 mA, -0.45 V ).

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @Qmechanic Possibly. You can migrate it if you like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How would you find the output voltage and current

Swap the diode position with the 4k7 resistor and then "merge" the volt drop of the diode into the 10 volt supply. This problem then becomes a 9.3 volt supply feeding two series resistors where the bottom resistor is attached to - 5 volts.

There is 14.3 volts across those resistors and the total resistance is (4.7 + 2.2) kohm. Therefore the current flowing is 2.0725 mA.

This means that the output voltage is -5 volts + (2.2 kohm * 2.0725 mA) =

-0.4406 volts.